# Logic behind 'or' operator in strings

Tags: python, string, logic, operators

Currently I'm studying on for loops and I've been given an assessment to get a better grab of it which was asking for me to printing only the words starting with 's' in the following string

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
```

and I wrote that simple codeline to get the job done

```
for word in st.split():
    if word[0] == 's' or 'S':
        print (word)
```

which resulted in following output

```
Print
only
the
words
that
start
with
s
in
this
sentence
```

The point couldn't grasp on is if I use `and` operator between 's' and 'S' or don't even use and operator between them (by demolishing 'S' of course.) instead of 'or' operator. I get the desired result which is:

```
start
s
sentence
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how I failed to understand the difference between them would be very much appreciated

Comment: `if word[0] == 's' or word[0] ==  'S'`:

Comment: Try `if word[0] == 's' or word[0] == 'S':`

Comment: The issue here appears to be that the string literal `'S'` is evaluating to true.  Therefore, ti doesn't even matter what the first letter is, because the boolean expression would always be true.  I'm not sure if Devesh's duplicate link is appropriate here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, now I see that was the main issue but I literally have no idea why it has happened and how can I use this codeline with my desired 'S' outputs

Comment: @YektaAktaş Read the very first comment under your question `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tjx, I see now strings themself considered to be true so my codeline printed out every single word instead  of what I am looking for

Comment: Yeah...it's an insidious bug actually, because in many (most?) other programming languages, such syntax would not even compile.  Python, being a scripting language, is a bit more forgiving and allows the script to run (albeit not with the logic you really want).